# Why does my OPCache keeps resetting at midnight everyday?

Tags: php

My Opcache keeps resetting, I even increased opcache.max_wasted_percentage to 50 but it still keeps restarting. Any idea why it keeps happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the logrotate was resetting apache at midnight. I removed

```
postrotate
            if invoke-rc.d apache2 status > /dev/null 2>&1; then \
                invoke-rc.d apache2 reload > /dev/null 2>&1; \
            fi;
endscript
```

from the file at /etc/logrotate.d/apache2 and now opcache does not reset anymore at midnight.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47688/how-to-avoid-apache-reload-when-rotating-logs

Answer (score 0):

the reseting relation is defined by revalidate_freq and validate_timestamps; if the latest is disabled then you have to reset manually. btw if I understood right your image shows no restart occurrences.

Comment: You can see it restarted 9 hours ago and it keeps happening and I have the timespamp check disabled.